# I just bought an SSL cert... What's next?

Tags: php, ssl, https, shared-hosting

I'm on a shared linux server with hostgator.com and I just had them install my first SSL certificate (free with the Business plan). Basically, what i want to know is: What's next?

How do enable encryption of data so I can send CC information to the server?
Am I supposed to set up my domain so it now goes to https:// instead of http://? If so, how?
Is there anything I need to do with my PHP scripts to do this properly?

I'm really new to this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Please see these pages:

- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-tools/ssl-certificates/how-do-i-use-the-third-party-ssl-certificate-i-purchased
- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-tools/ssl-certificates/im-going-to-purchase-my-own-ssl-what-do-i-need-to-know
- http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-tools/ssl-certificates/how-to-set-up-and-use-your-shared-ssl

> Am I supposed to set up my domain so
>   it now goes to https:// instead of
>   http://? If so, how?

Apache will need to be configured.  There is nothing you need to do with DNS.  Read the Hostgator docs for how to get this setup through them.

> Is there anything I need to do with my
>   PHP scripts to do this properly?

You may need to adjust some configuration files, or update any scripts that have hard coded the URLs.

Comment: @Zoredache, I should have specified that I got the cert from Hostgator through their Business plan. Does that mean the work is done and the site is now secure?

Comment: I think you'll need to ask hostgator support.  They should be able to give you a very prompt response to a straightforward question like that :)

Comment: I tried once and I admit I was being impatient, but you all know a hell-of-a-lot more than most of the tech reps there.